# SQL Create Row Number, skip certain row numbers

Tags: sql, row-number

I am trying to create row numbers in SQL but do not want to use certain numbers.

Example Illustration:

```
 Bob, 100
 Matt, 120
 Dan, 150
 Bill, 156
 Tim, 175
```

Normally in SQL....if I were to use the Row_Number() function...it would count - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I would instead like to skip certain numbers so that it counts - 1, 2, 5, 6, 7

Below is my code

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN clean_client_nm = 'Total Opportunities' 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY clean_ft_ee DESC) 
    END AS row_id,
    prod,
    client_nm,
    clean_ft_ee,
    ISNULL(Med, ''),
    ISNULL(Stop, ''),
    ISNULL(Den, ''),
    ISNULL(VIS, ''),
    ISNULL(Life, ''),
    ISNULL(STD, ''),
    ISNULL(LTD, ''),
    ISNULL(Worksite, ''),
    client_sic
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM TOTAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM BASE) AS X
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN clean_client_nm = 'Total Opportunities' 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE 1 
    END,
    clean_ft_ee DESC, client_nm
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for skipping.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just trying to optimize the code so that when it is pasted in to an excel spreadsheet, I can simply print the sheet and it is formatted properly. In other words, no heavy formulas or vba code to manipulate.

Comment: Dynamic SQL with a FOR loop.  Just increment your iterator when you find a value you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to create a temp/variable table and insert the specified values a user needs and then to use the FirstCursor logic to sequentially update the row_id fields in the table needed.

```
    declare FirstCursor cursor global for select row_num from @row_num
    open FirstCursor
       while @count > 0
          begin
             fetch FirstCursor into @row_id;
             with top1 as (
             select top 1 lives, row_id
             from @singlecovclient
             where row_id is null order by lives desc)
             update top1 set row_id = @row_id
             set @count = @count - 1
           end
    close FirstCursor
    deallocate FirstCursor
```